# IE not displaying ajax call results from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

question says it all... code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                dataToLoad = 'showresults=true';
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'submit.php',
                    datatype: 'html',
                    data: dataToLoad,
                    async: true,
                    success: function(data){

                        $('#results').html(data);   
                    },

                });
});
```

Comment: Have you alerted your data? What's that give you?

Comment: alerted ok on extra browsers... the fix was actually the comma after the closing success bracket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
dataType: 'html'
```

instead of

```
datatype: 'html'
```

and remove the trailing comma at the end (IE<=7 will throw error)

If the problem persists, add an error callback to see if there's an error

```
error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown){
   alert("Error:\n" + status);
}
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers